# Getting Esri Brushes to appear as dynamic resources in Visual Studio?

Tags: arcgis-pro, visual-studio, wpf, arcgis-pro-sdk

I used the ArcGIS Pro SDK to create my Add-In project and to create the DockPane but the Esri Brushes don't show up as Dynamic Resources.

According to Esri (https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/proguide-style-guide)

"ArcGIS Pro XAML styles should be used as DynamicResources while styling the UI elements in an add-in. Add this code snippet to your xaml so that these Dynamic resources will load in Design mode in Visual Studio."

```
<UserControl ...
      xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions;assembly=ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions"
      ...>
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     <extensions:DesignOnlyResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework;component\Themes\Default.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

However, the SDK already puts this reference in the .xaml file but no dynamic resources show up in the Designer options. And manually typing in the Esri Brush name doesn't do anything.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Can you provide a screen shot of your .xaml for the control. Do you get any errors when manually specifying the brush and then building?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [ProGuide Style Guide](https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/proguide-style-guide), opening a XAML (Extensible Application Markup Language) file using the Visual Studio Designer view can result in the following error in ArcGIS Pro version 2.8 and above:

> Could not load file or assembly `'ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework, Culture=neutral'` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
> the file specified.

The XAML files that produce the error message typically contain a reference to the Pro API, which is usually included with Pro SDK item templates in the form of a xmlns attribute line item such as:

```
xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions;assembly=ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions"
```

Whereas previous ArcGIS Pro assemblies were built with the `AnyCPU` platform target, at ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and above, many of the assemblies are now built using the 64-bit platform target. The XAML Designer that ships with Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 is not capable of loading x64 assemblies. This causes the error message.

**References**:

- https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000025543
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xaml-designer-does-not-display-x64-user-controls-f/699887